# Why my activity reCreate and not reStart

Tags: android

i start my activity by this

```
 Intent window = new Intent(mContext, popup.class);
 window.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);  
 mContext.startActivity(window);
```

my activity was started and the log

```
 onCreate
 onStart
 onResume
```

now i want to stop my activity i use this

```
 moveTaskToBack(true); //i don't know if this best way to stop an activity
```

and the Log

```
onPause
onStoped
```

> onDestroy not called

now i want to reStart same activity i use

```
   Intent window = new Intent(mContext, popup.class);
   window.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);  
   mContext.startActivity(window);
```

here its not restart the activity its make new one

```
 onCreate
 onStart
 onResume
```

and this is my activity in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.popup"
        android:taskAffinity=".MyDialog"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:ignore="ExportedActivity"

        >

  </activity>
```

note ** if i use launchMode  `singleInstance` its restart and not create new activity but here problem i cant Instance same activity for different data

Comment: You're creating a new instance of your activity by calling `Intent window = new Intent(mContext, popup.class)` even without the flags, which explicitly state that it's the new task and unrelated to the one sent to the back. So your *new* activity goes through the basic Android lifecycle: onCreate, onStart etc.

Comment: @NitroNbg so the solution how can i start  my stopped activity ?

Comment: use finish() to stop

Comment: Have you tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` together with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`?

Comment: @IshitaSinha and yes i try it without remove 
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`

Comment: @VV finish destroy my activity when i used it

Answer (score 0):

Dont add this flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and also add this tag to your activity in manifest `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
when use it i cant lunch same activity with different data
  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` iam use this because i start activity from context none activity

Comment: but `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` make my activity restart without reCraete but i cant lunch the activity again with different data

Comment: why cant you can add different paramas at every launch no problem.

Comment: wait i will try add different extra for every activity and i will response to you

Comment: not work .. using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` start new activity and stop it now start same activity with another data (multi activity) ... not started